# Android studio with gcm

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

i am trying  a jsp page sends to a android app.i am choosing gcm for send message from java web app to android app and receive the messege from java web application.how is it possible?.

Comment: It is not clear question. After what, this problem accured? did u add any library ?gradle sync error could have several reasons

Comment: Connect to internet and sync your gradle again. After that go to Preferences -> Gradle -> Global Gradle Settings -> Offline work

Comment: Please click on the error, copy it on your clipboard, [edit] your question, and paste it in your question (after enclosing it in code markup). Screenshots of errors don't help anybody. They're difficult to google and impossible to index (for future visitors having the same error). Having the original text is a thousands time better. After you're done with that, please delete that image, and reset/change your api key. You also inadvertently published your api key in that screenshot. Also, please tell us what specific steps you took to try to resolve this issue yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try connect with Internet and re-sync with gradle it may help you.